# Spring JPA Transient list not initialized

Tags: spring, jpa, javafx, transient

Since I want to use ObservableLists in my entities classes within JavaFX, originally I had a problem with the dedicated List implementation and injection over reflection that Hibernate is using by default. Therefore I decided to have my Entity classes annotated with `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`, because I want to enforce that Hibernate uses my getter and setter methods and not reflection.

In a particular class I have a number of List attributes e.g. `protected List<CostEstimate> costEstimates;`. For each of these lists I have getters and setters which are annotated accordingly. So far so good, that seems to work. 
The trouble is that in my UI I don't want to show e.g. all costEstimates that were created over time, but only the last one. So I created a method `public CostEstimate getLastCostEstimate()` which would return only the last element from the List. This method is annotated with @Transient since there is no matching column in the MySQL database, since it only returns the last element from the related list.

My controller class binds `getLastCostEstimate()` of the entity to the according UI element.

In the default constructor of my entity class the costEstimates list is initialized with a initial default estimate, such that `getLastCostEstimate()` should always return a meaningful CostEstimate. In the debugger I can see that this initialization is executed. However, at run time the costEstimates list is empty and I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I assume that has to do with the @Transient annotation ?! I wonder whether I have a coding or design issue? I guess my question is: how to model this "give me only the last element from a list" in a JPA entity class (without too much boilerplate code)?

Thank you for your help!

For your convenience please find following some related code snippets:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)    // JPA reading and writing attributes through their accessor getter and setter methods
public abstract class UserRequirement extends Requirement implements Serializable {
..
    protected List<CostEstimate> costEstimates; // Money needed 
..
    protected UserRequirement() {
        ..
        costEstimates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        setLastCostEstimate(new CostEstimate(0));
        ..
    }

..
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<CostEstimate> getCostEstimates() {
         return costEstimates;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")     // Used by JPA
    public void setCostEstimates(List<CostEstimate> newCostEstimates) {

        if(newCostEstimates != null) {

      ((ObservableList<CostEstimate>)costEstimates).setAll(newCostEstimates);   
        } else {
            costEstimates.clear();
        }
    }

    @Transient
    public CostEstimate getLastCostEstimate() {

        return costEstimates.get(costEstimates.size()-1);
    }

    public void setLastCostEstimate(CostEstimate costEstimate) {
        if(costEstimate = null) {
            return;
        }
        costEstimates.add(costEstimate);
    }

..
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the result of using `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` for fetching the results. Directly accessing the field should prevent the lazy fetching of the results. Using `List<CostEstimate> estimates = getCostEstimates(); return estimates.get(estimates.size()-1);` may work...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. The estimates that I get using getCostEstimates() is also empty. I also limited the getter annotation to @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent"), still the same behavior. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If a particular `UserRequirement` does not have any associated `CostEstimate`s in the db, then obviously, when loading it from the DB, JPA will initialize it using the default constructor (which results in adding an element to `costEstimates`), and then immediately call `setCostEstimates` with an empty collection, thus clearing `costEstimates`. How is that surprising?

Comment: Hi Crizzis. Thank you for your feedback. I guess I understand what you are saying. But how do I "initialize" a lists if I can't do it in the constructor?